# Masked Date-Time input without p:calendar

Tags: primefaces

With an `inputMask` component, you can't easily validate the date format, and you have to parse the string to a date/time in the background; whereas with the `calendar` component, you can set an input mask so the users can type the date; however when they click on the field it pops up the calendar.

What I would like, is for the keyboard-input functionality of the `calendar` control (masked input, bound to date object) to be kept, but without the physical calendar popup. Is there an option to do this?

What I currently have:

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.someDateTimeBackingField}"
pattern="yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm" 
timeZone="#{bean.tz}" 
navigator="true" 
mask="true" />
```

I am using Primefaces version 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `showOn="button"` attribute, the popup won't show on focus. The user can either input a date or choose to pick it from the popup after touching the button.

If you want to hide the button, you might do so by CSS or set a value of the `showOn` attribute to something that does not exist:

```
    <p:calendar value="#{bean.someDateTimeBackingField}"
        pattern="yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm" timeZone="#{bean.tz}" mask="true"
        showOn="trustlessComputing" />
```